# How can i use mysql credential with special character with python conenct string

Tags: python, mysql, oracle

I wish to know how can I parse password with a special character (@) using python and MySQL.

I tried this way:

```
password='\"abc@r\"'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(username+'/'+password+'@'+sid)
```

And it did not work.You help is much appreciated

Comment: `cx_Oracle`, but [tag:mysql]?  Which are you using?

Comment: Basically, refer to connection string format documentation. It's really just a string passed to and interpreted by a DB client library.

Comment: Hello ,Indeed i must to deal with Oracle and sql .Its kind of known issue with sqlplus that it can't directly deal with credentials with special character unless we use escape with '\'.So i would like to make use the same in python and its keep failing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it with below syntaxt .thank you all
connection = cx_Oracle.connect (user='XXX' ,password='XXX@r',dsn='DB :1522/SID')